# Solution to system of multivariate quadratic equations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, numerical-methods

I am looking for a numerical solution to a system of quadratic equations of the form:

$$
    \mathbf{x}^T A_i \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{c}=0 ~~~~~~~~ i = 1,..,N
$$

I am aware of the various solution methods for general systems of polynomial equations, such as Grobner bases etc. Is there a simpler/faster solution in the case of pure quadratic equations?

Comment: An exact solution is $x=0$.

Comment: @Michael Good point! Looking back at my original problem, I now realize there are lower-order terms that I forgot to include. Updated!

Comment: Can’t you apply Newton-Raphson?

Comment: You added the extra coefficients quickly and I wonder if you really meant the bold-face $\mathbf{c}$ to be a scalar $c$, or perhaps a scalar $c_i$ for each $i \in \{1, ..., N\}$?  Same for $\mathbf{b}$ versus $\mathbf{b}_i$, and is $x$ assumed to be of dimension $k$ not related to $N$?